# bootstrap tooltip with multiple triggers

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to use tooltip() on multiple triggers. For example :hover and focus

The problem is bootstrap tooltip css is applied for the first trigger action and for the second trigger action default browser tooltip is applied instead of bootstrap css.

```
function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element)
                    .attr('title', attrs.clickTooltip)
                    .tooltip({ trigger: "focus" }, { placement: "top" });

                $(element)
                    .attr('title', attrs.clickTooltip)
                    .tooltip({ trigger: "hover" }, { placement: "top" });
```

}

i have tried this way also:

```
 $(element)
                    .attr('title', attrs.clickTooltip)
                    .tooltip({ trigger: "hover focus" }, { placement: "top" });
```

Any help is appreciated..Thanks in advance

Comment: post your html or provide us a fiddle to get a better answer..

Comment: <input type="text" data-click-tooltip="Test tooltip"/>  this is the directive   module.directive('clickTooltip', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    $(element)
                        .attr('title', attrs.clickTooltip)
                        .tooltip({ trigger: "focus" }, { placement: "top" });

                    $(element)
                        .attr('title', attrs.clickTooltip)
                        .tooltip({ trigger: "hover" }, { placement: "top" });
} } });